# If $x^n=y^n$ and $n$ is odd then $x=y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here, we suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $x^n=y^n$, where $n$ is odd. I want to prove that $x=y$.

Maybe we can use that $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

So, it suffices to show that if $x^n=y^n$ then $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}\neq 0$

Any hint?

Answer (score 6):

Since $n$ is odd, $x^n=y^n$ implies that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. We may therefore assume that they are both strictly positive. But then $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}$ is strictly positive and so cannot be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged "calculus" you may want to show that $f(x) = x^n$ is increasing using the derivative of $f$.

EDIT: the tag has since been changed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Verify that for $x=0$, $y=0$ is the only solution and trivially $x=y$ for this case. Now let $z = \frac yx, x \neq 0$.

Then $y^n - x^n = x^n(z^n - 1)$

Zeroes of the LHS are zeroes of the RHS.

Meaning that $z^n - 1 = 0$.

Consider the $n$-th roots of unity for odd $n$.

Can you continue from there?

Answer (score 2):

***A Proof by Contradiction:***

Suppose $ x \neq y$. Then $ x \gt y $ or $x \lt y$. Consider the first case. It won't hurt to suppose that $x , y \gt 0$. I shall explain a little later. Now let us prove the statement $ x^n \gt y^n $ by induction on $n$. Base case is our assumption. Suppose $ x^n \gt y^n $. Since we know that $x \gt y \gt 0$ we can multiply the two inequalities to obtain $x^{n + 1} \gt y^{n + 1}$. Hence we have that $$ x^n \gt y^n \;\; \forall n \in \Bbb N  $$

Hence $  x^n = y^n $ for some odd $n \in \Bbb N$ is impossible leading to a contradiction.

Now the second case: $ x \lt y$ is almost identical.

Now what if the signs of $x$ and $y$ were different. Again without loss of generality assume $ x \lt 0 \lt y $. Now prove by induction that $ x^n = (-1)^n|x|^n $. Then for odd $n$ we have that $ x^n = (-1)^n|x|^n \lt 0 \lt y^n$ leading to a contradiction. The case for $ x \gt 0 \gt y $ is again identical.

One more case,  if $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$. Prove by induction that $y^n \neq 0$ for each $n \Bbb N$. But then $x^n = 0$ leads to a contradiction. The case for $ y = 0 $ and $x \neq 0$ is almost identical.

All cases are exhausted (*I think*). Didn't think it would be this long when I started writing.