# $x^n < y^n$ implies $x < y$ proof

Tags: inequality

I have already proved $ x < y => x^n < y^n $

I am currently trying to prove the converse statement, but I am getting nowhere. The textbook suggests trying to set up a contradiction, but I can't seem to succeed with this.

Comment: What course are you taking? You could take the $n$th root of both sides, but this would probably not be allowed.

Comment: Proofs. I don't think that would be allowed either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $x^n=y^n$ and $n$ is odd then $x=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903966/if-xn-yn-and-n-is-odd-then-x-y) The correct statement should be for $n$ odd unless $x,y > 0$.

Comment: You can use Approach0 to check if there are any duplicates before you ask.

Comment: This is only true, if we restrict to non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It is trivial that $x=y\implies x^n=y^n$ and you already know that $x>y\implies x^n>y^n$. In other words, $x\geqslant y\implies x^n\geqslant y^n$. And this is equivalent to $x^n<y^n\implies x<y$.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to prove this by way of contradiction, do the following:

Let's start with $x^n < y^n$, and if possible, assume $x \geq y$. Now, raising the latter inequality to the $n^{th}$ power gives $x^n \geq y^n$, which contradicts $x^n < y^n$. Our assumption $x \geq y$ must be incorrect.

So, $x < y$.

One thing that really bothers me is the constraints on $x,y,$ and $n$ - this relation won't hold for all values of $(x,y,n)$, and I encourage you to figure out necessary constraints. A contradictory example is as follows:
$$-2 < -1 \nRightarrow (-2)^2 < (-1)^2$$